# Size of the largest disk not intersecting N random points on the 2D torus

Tags: probability, geometry, geometric-probability

Consider $N$ points generated uniformly at random on the 2d torus (ie. unit square after identifying right/left and up/down). I am interested in estimating the size (eg. diameter) of the largest disk that does not intersect any of these N points. Even estimating the rate of decay of the expected diameter would be a good start!

In 1D (ie. a circle), this is quite well-known and has been discussed several times on this form. The 2D case seems more complicated.

PS: the torus is the simplest 2D object I could think of (ie. no boundary effects). If this makes things easier to work on the unit square, I would also be very interested!

Comment: Perhaps considering a Poisson point process  (i.e., $N$ is not fixed, only its mean) is slightly more tractable. See eg https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-1-4614-1966-2_4